# Cleanup small commits on master branch

Tags: git

Git time! My `master` branch goes trashy last time. I overslept and didn't create a branch for my minor fixes and made some commits. I have this:

```
(R1)<---(R2)<---(c1)<---(c2)<---(c3)             master
 Rx - releases
 cX - some fixes
```

I would like to have something like this on separate branch:

```
(R1)<---(R2)                                     master
          \
           \<---(c1)<---(c2)<---(c3)             last-fixes
```

And next merge this to `master` with `--no-ff`:

```
(R1)<---(R2)<-------------------------(R3)       master
          \                          /
           \<---(c1)<---(c2)<---(c3)/            last-fixes
```

How to make this in simple steps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a new branch at your current position, reset `master` to a previous commit, and then merge it with `--no-ff`

```
git branch last-fixes
git reset R2 --hard
git merge last-fixes --no-ff
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  Also remember that this is changing history of master and if the master branch has been pushed to a remote it will cause trouble.

Comment: This is my case. I have already pushed stuff to remote, but I am only one person in project. Can I just make `git push -f` after this changes?

Comment: @flyer Yes, you can do that. Since you are the only one that is accessing the remote at this time.  If that were not the case, You don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you are on the branch master.

```
git checkout master
```

Then create a branch for your fixes

```
git branch last-fixes
```

Now reset master to where it should be

```
git reset --hard <R2>
```

And you can merge your merges

```
git merge --no-ff last-fixes
```